# Partially deleting old text of QML::Text while updating it with new text

Tags: qt, text, qml

I have the following QML Text embedded inside a Rectangle

```
Rectangle {
    id: textContainer
    border.color: "black"

    Text {
        id: myTextView
        anchors.fill: textContainer
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.pointSize: 4
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap

        Connections {
            target: cpp_controller
            onUpdateCalledFromCppCode: {
                myTextView.text = message + myTextView.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`onUpdateCalledFromCppCode` gets called like twice or thrice in a second which updates `myTextView::text` field. This works very well.

**Question:**
I want to delete the older text. Like if the text is more that 10 lines, I want to delete the 11th and the rest of it. This is to show a continious update making it look like rolling down with updated text all the time. Is there a standard way to do this in `QML`?

Comment: delete part of a string and add the new one to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `clip: true` does the trick I was looking for.

Thus, my `Text` QML item displays only what could be made visible within the `Text` QML item area and updates the latest in the visible area. Note, in the question I posted . I am prepending the new text to `Text:text` not appending.